# Is it considering security allowed to use a p12 file as a client certificate?

Tags: c#, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Because I've read that a `.p12` file also contains the private key and I know that private keys shouldn't be sent through the internet. I'm asking myself if I can use the `.p12` file as a client certificate as below for establishing a **https** connection.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\....p12", new NetworkCredential("", "password").SecurePassword);
```

Comment: The file must be a PKCS7 signed file. p12 is PKCS12.  A PKCS12 may contain a PKCS #7 DigestInfo

Comment: @jdweng Can I generate a PKCS7 file from the p12 file I have now? And can I know which one I have? (PKCS7 or PKCS12)

Comment: @jdweng I created a P7B file with complete certificate chain, but I receive a `CryptographicException`: `Cannot find the original signer`. With p12 it works.

Comment: When you present a client cert only the signed public key is sent to the server.